# How to significantly reduce apache2 average process size?

Tags: memory, server, process, webserver, apache2

**Current config:**

16GO RAM, 4 cpu cores, Apache/2.2 using prefork module (which is set at 700 maxClients, since avg process size ~18MB), with suexec and suphp mods enabled (PHP 5.5).

Back-end of site using CakePHP2 and storing on a MySQL server. The site consists of text / some compressed images in the front and data processing in the back.

I use this shell script to calculate my avg process size:

```
total_httpd_processes_size=`ps -ylC apache2 --sort:rss | awk '{ sum += $9 } END { print sum }'`                                                                               
total_http_processes_count=`ps -ylC apache2 --sort:rss | wc -l`
echo "total_http_processes_count=$total_http_processes_count"
AVG_httpd_process_size=$(expr $total_httpd_processes_size / $total_http_processes_count)
httpd_process_size_MB=$(expr $AVG_httpd_process_size / 1024)
echo "httpd_process_size_MB=$total_httpd_process_size_MB"
```

By disabling unused apache mods, I won ~4mb which is pretty nice (from 22mb to 18mb).

What else can I do to significantly reduce the AVG process size ?

Comment: Please post to pastebin.com the last 400 lines of your slow.log file for analysis.  If you have no entries in your slow.log, please SET GLOBAL long_query_time=1; for a 1 second query time limit to trigger a logged event. With your current 10 second limit, you will only trigger 1 logged event per hour. After you share some slow queries, you may want to go to 5 second limit for general purposes of awareness.

Comment: Hi Wilson. You already gave me some suggestions for `mysql` and thank you for that, but I'm fine with it, I already worked on slow queries on that side.